# How to make a route map of my all trips in a year?

Tags: webapp-rec

I tried with Google Maps, by adding destinations, but because I traveled a lot in Google Maps I can only add A - Z (31 destinations).

I'm looking for a free online map tool that can show all my trips from a year in one map.

I also want to indicate which travel was by road, by train, by air or by water and to calculate total time and kilometers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that **Google Map's "My Places"** feature can do all these things for you. I do something quite similar myself.

### Relevant functionality

- **It's free**
- **It copes with many more than 31 destinations** (I've got a map with 200 places marked, for example)
- **Showing destinations**

  - You could create a named map for each year, for example "My trips 2011" etc
  - You can add markers for named places, to represent your destinations.
  - There are marker icons for many types of travel - taxi, bus, train, plane, boat, helicopter, tram, sailing, walking, cycling, horse....!
  - You can change the colours and symbols for these place markers, if you want to give them some meaning
- **Showing trips**

  - You can draw lines on the map, to indicate routes between places
  - And you can change the colours of lines, so you could have a colour scheme to indicate whether the route was by road, train etc
  - When you click on a line/route, it shows you the "Total distance"
  - You can add notes to record how long the journey took, but I don't think it can calculate this for you

### Getting started

If you don't already have maps set up on Google:

- Go to http://maps.google.com/maps (or whatever country you're in)
- Click on 'My places'
- Sign in
- Click "CREATE MAP"
- Start work on your map...

There is Support info for Google Maps at http://maps.google.com/support/

There is an introductory [Video on Creating custom maps](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62843&topic=1687289) that gives quite a good introduction. Although it shows a short route, everything it describes would work well for larger scale routes too.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at Travel Pod.

My brother uses it to show the routes for his cycling trips:
http://blog.travelpod.com/travel-blog/jnewcomb/cycletour-2005/tpod.html

It allows you to keep a kind of diary where you can specify where you are on a daily bases, upload a few photos and write a journal. Your locations are plotted on a Google map in chronological order. Try hovering over the green blobs sitting above the Google map.

As far as I know you can have as many destinations on the map as you like.

Answer (score 0):

We have [a mapping tool](http://www.travellerspoint.com/member_map.cfm) on Travellerspoint that does pretty much exactly what you would want.

It is built on top of Google Maps and allows you to quickly map out all your trips individually, and have a map shown with them all on there with lines between the markers.

We also show stats of all your trips on pages like [this one](http://www.travellerspoint.com/stats/Utrecht/).

There's a lot of other features tied into it also, but it can certainly do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another nice tool is http://www.mapmytrips.com  It is particularly good if you store trip photos in Picasa. And there is a page which would list all your trips.